# Chaining C++ stream manipulators into single variable

Tags: c++, ofstream, manipulators

I am chaining some stream manipulators in an ofstream like so:

```
std::string filename = "output.txt";
std::ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.open(filename, std::ios::trunc);
outputFile << std::setw(5) << std::scientific << std::left << variable;
```

Is it possible to do something like this instead?:

```
std::string filename = "output.txt";
std::ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.open(filename, std::ios::trunc);
std::ostream m;
m << std::setw(5) << std::scientific << std::left;   // Combine manipulators into a single variable
outputFile << m << variable;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A stream manipulator is just a function that a stream calls on itself through one of the [`operator <<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) overloads (10-12 in the link). You just have to declare such a function (or something convertible to a suitable function pointer):

```
constexpr auto m = [](std::ostream &s) -> std::ostream& {
    return s << std::setw(5) << std::scientific << std::left;
};
std::cout << m << 12.3 << '\n';
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VNpN4lTPmhpTpg4W)

Comment: this is great. Trailing return type is required to return a reference, right?

Comment: @idclev463035818 precisely :)

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own manipulator:

```
struct my_manipulator{};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const my_manipulator& mm) {
     o << std::setw(5) << std::scientific << std::left;
     return o;
};
```

This would allow you to write

```
outputFile << my_manipulator{} << variable;
```

PS: Io-manipulators modify the state of the stream. Hence it cannot work exactly the way you asked for. You are modifying the state of `m`. Transferring the state from one stream to another is possible, but imho more complicated than necessary.

PPS: Note that my way of defining a custom io-manipulator is ok-ish, but to see an implementation that is more in the spirit of stream manipulators see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60562410/4117728) (usually io-manipulators are functions, I used a tag which requires a tiny bit more boilerplate).